# how to update etherpad-lite properly?

Tags: node.js, etherpad

I keep totally failing to update an etherpad-lite server. The problem: Even a Google search for the update procedure brings up hardly any information, only that one should run "git pull origin".

I have now tried this in many different ways. The update usually works, but afterwards one of these errors occurs:

- Plugins can no longer be installed
- The service can no longer be started (TypeError: log4js.replaceConsole is not a function)
- The entire admin panel no longer works.

I tried uninstalling or updating all plug-ins before, but both hardly brought any improvements, only other errors. The update of the plugins in the admin console fails, I tried it via the updatePlugins.sh script. Here a message appears that at least etherpad-lite 1.8,6 must be installed. I am currently at version 1.8.4 and would like to update to the latest version 1.8.12. However, some of the plug-ins are still updated. A very strange behaviour.

I would be happy if someone could tell me how to properly update the etherpad-lite instance step by step.  (ubuntu 20)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently updated Etherpad-lite from version *1.8.6* to *1.8.13*.

For me, executing `git pull origin` and then checking out the 1.8.13 release tag, with `git checkout 1.8.13`, made the work.

It is important, despite having Etherpad configured as a service, to run it for the first time using:
`src/bin/run.sh`.

- Node v12.22.1
- npm 6.14.12
- Ubuntu 20.04.2

I hope it has been useful to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I skipped the last versions, but today I made the upgrade exactly like this and it works. I think I forgot to run the run.sh script last time.

Comment: If you don't want to switch to latest `origin/develop` branch, you should use `git fetch` followed by `git checkout 1.8.13` (or `git merge 1.8.13` if you have made local commits). If you use `git pull` it will technically do `git fetch` followed by `git merge` behind the curtains.